# Подскажите, аналог len для ChatMemberUpdated

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Для Message, у меня, прописано так:

```
new_chat_members = len(message.new_chat_members)
```

Если, участник группы, отправляет текст, то в колонке new_chat_members 0 и когда пригласит, показывает, количество, сколько пригласил.

Для ChatMemberUpdated:
Если участник группы, не отправлял текст и сразу, добавил контакты, то таблица не заполняется, так как, нельзя выбрать, как в Message

```
len(message.new_chat_members)
```

**Так нельзя**

```
len(message.new_chat_member)
```

и так, тоже нельзя

```
len(update.new_chat_members)
```

```
new_chat_members = message.new_chat_member
new_chat_members = update.new_chat_member
```

Нужно, чтобы в бд записалось количества, приглашенных контактов, в группу телеграм.

len возвращает длину (количество элементов) объекта.

Прописал, вот так

```
new_chat_members = len(int(message.new_chat_member))
```

Пишет, ошибку

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```